# Session data working on local but not on ipage server

Tags: php

I have been trying to debug this problem for hours but couldn't. I have these two files:

My first file:

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['user'] = '1';
```

My second file:

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
echo $_SESSION['user'];
```

But The second file echoes an empty array. This works fine on my localhost but didn't work on online server. I also have 'register_globals' turned off in php.ini

Comment: what do you get for `var_dump(session_start());` in your online server?

Comment: cookies accepted? else use `SID` as parameter

Comment: for var_dump(session_start()); it gives "bool(true)"

Comment: seems session data isn't persisting

Comment: This is happening to me too right now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using cPanel goto `cPanel` > `php.ini QuickConfig` >

Check for

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = /tmp
```

If you have still facing the problem ask your cPanel guys they will help you

Comment: Good answer. If there's no /tmp, you can prefer /var/tmp

Answer (score 7):

i was also facing the same issue with ipage hosting now it is solved with Radhakrishna Chowdary`s help i did following-

1. login to your ipage hosting account
2. go to Additional Tools -> CGI and Scripted Language Support
3. there choose PHP Scripting
4. there you will see "Edit your php.ini file for PHP 5.3" click on
   edit.
5. change value of session.save_path `s value  to "/tmp"
6. its done working now :)

Comment: To be exact change this value **`session.save_path = "/var/php_sessions"**

Answer (score 3):

iPage requires you to specify the `session_save_path()` within your script. Like so :

```
session_save_path("your home directory path"/cgi-bin/tmp);
session_start();
```

Take a look at this [iPage Knowledgebase article](http://www.ipage.com/knowledgebase/read_article.bml?kbid=600) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the session variables like $_SESSION['user'] to $_SESSION['userr']
as changing the variable names worked for me for php 5.3 on ipage

Answer (score 0):

Changing 'session.save_path' is not working I tried this a lot but nothing fixed, I contact there support to fix the issue for me, but they said session is disabled in ipage, which is something very bad for cPanel site.

But anyway I recommend another hosting service since iPage doesn't support session which is something main in php development for login and save data.

---

I recently receive this from IPage customer service:

this mean that the "**session.save_path**" will never change in 'php.ini',  you have to do it in your code as mentioned from there customer service.

[image]

Remember to add this line **before session start**

```
session_save_path('/home/your/home/directory/path/cgi-bin/tmp');
```